# Insert an SQL Row If Does Not Already Exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am currently using the code:

```
INSERT INTO tradecounts 
SELECT symbol, tstamp, COUNT(*) AS trades 
FROM (SELECT d.* FROM janw1 d ORDER BY entry_date ASC LIMIT 200000) d 
GROUP BY tstamp, symbol HAVING COUNT(*) > 50
```

Which is working as intended however I would like to use python to run this statement every n number of seconds and when it does that it appends duplicate records so I need to put a WHERE NOT EXISTS statement in but I am having trouble with the syntax

```
insert INTO tradecounts 
SELECT symbol, tstamp, COUNT(*) AS trades 
FROM (SELECT d.* FROM janw1 d ORDER BY entry_date ASC LIMIT 200000) d 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
GROUP BY tstamp, symbol HAVING COUNT(*) > 50
```

Any suggestions as to where I am going wrong would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: create a unique index on `symbol, tstamp` then use `insert .. on conflict (..) do nothing`

Comment: Why don't you create a unique constraint?

Comment: Do you really want *ascending* on entry_date?  That seems counterintuitive?

Answer (score 1):

Following query should work.

```
INSERT INTO tradecounts 
SELECT symbol, tstamp, COUNT(*) AS trades 
FROM (SELECT d.* FROM janw1 d ORDER BY entry_date ASC LIMIT 200000) d 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
SELECT 1 FROM tradecounts tc where tc.symbol=d.symbol and tc.tstamp=d.tstamp
)
GROUP BY tstamp, symbol HAVING COUNT(*) > 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `on conflict`.  First define a unique index or constraint on the first two columns;

```
create unique index unq_symbol_tstamp on tradecounts(symbol, tstamp);

insert INTO tradecounts (symbol, tstamp, trades)
    SELECT symbol, tstamp, COUNT(*) AS trades 
    FROM (SELECT d.*
          FROM janw1 d
          ORDER BY entry_date ASC
          LIMIT 200000
         ) d 
    GROUP BY tstamp, symbol
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 50
    ON CONFLICT (symbol, tstamp) DO
        UPDATE SET trades = excluded.trades;
```

This also has the advantage that is will update any timestamps where the count has changed.

Actually, you want to be a little careful to be sure you have full timestamps.  That suggests:

```
create unique index unq_symbol_tstamp on tradecounts(symbol, tstamp);

insert INTO tradecounts (symbol, tstamp, trades)
    SELECT symbol, tstamp, COUNT(*) AS trades 
    FROM (SELECT d.*, MIN(tstamp) OVER () as min_tstamp
          FROM (SELECT d.*
                FROM janw1 d
                ORDER BY entry_date DESC, tstamp DESC
                LIMIT 200000
              ) d 
         ) d 
    WHERE tstamp > min_tstamp
    GROUP BY tstamp, symbol
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 50
    ON CONFLICT (symbol, tstamp) DO
        UPDATE SET trades = excluded.trades;
```